# getting compile error for variable on ArrayAdapter method, Android

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

getting compile error for the "CheckBoxInfo" variable in the code below,  it is correct yet i get the error,

```
  listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.row_layout, CheckBoxInfo);
    listview.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

from the documents it says:  "the objects to represent in the Listview",  however CheckBoxInfo IS the objects to represent in the listview.  what is wrong here?

the rest of the code:

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
CheckBoxInfo cbr;
private ListAdapter MyAdapter;
ListView listview;
MyAdapter myAdapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    cbr = new CheckBoxInfo();
    cbr.checkBoxName = "dfdjklfjdkljf";
    cbr.checkBoxState = true;

    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.row_layout, CheckBoxInfo);
    listview.setAdapter(myAdapter);

}

public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CheckBoxInfo> {

     private List<CheckBoxInfo> checkBoxList;
    private Context context;

    public MyAdapter(List<CheckBoxInfo> infoList, Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.row_layout, infoList);
        this.checkBoxList = infoList;
        this.context = context;

        for(int i = 0; i <=12; i++){
            checkBoxList.add(cbr);
        }

    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // First let's verify the convertView is not null
        if (convertView == null) {
            // This a new view we inflate the new layout
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);
        }
            // Now we can fill the layout with the right values
            TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            CheckBoxInfo cbi = checkBoxList.get(position);

            tv.setText(cbi.checkBoxName);

        return convertView;
    }

}  // end MyAdapter
```

}

the other class, representing objects to populate the listview:

```
public class CheckBoxInfo {
 Boolean checkBoxState;
 String checkBoxName;

 public CheckBoxInfo(){
   checkBoxState = false;
   checkBoxName = "";
 }
```

}

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do I set the listView to the ArrayAdapter, Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15874049/how-do-i-set-the-listview-to-the-arrayadapter-android)

Comment: What is the compile error that you are getting?

Comment: getting cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: this is not a duplicate question,  i tried to get the answer from the other question to work in the code but it does not work so I have to ask further questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in the arguments you pass to the constructor

```
      listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
      List<CheckBoxInfo> ls = new ArrayList<CheckBoxInfo>();
      ls.add(cbr);
      myAdapter = new MyAdapter(ls, this);
      listview.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

And the override of toString function in CheckBoxInfo class

```
public String toString(){
    return "Name : " + checkBoxName + " , Checked : " + checkBoxState;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass a list of CheckBoxInfo elements in the ArrayAdapter constructor.

```
ArrayList<CheckBoxInfo> items = new ArrayList<CheckBoxInfo>();
// add elements to the list
(...)
myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.row_layout, items);
```

Answer (score 0):

See constructor of myAdapter class is having only 2 argument.and in your code you are calling constructor with 3 arguments.